# How many ways are there of arranging a group of 60 people into 3 different groups,

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

So there are 60 people, and i want to know how many ways there is to arrange them in to 3 groups, 2 groups of 22 and one group of 16. 
Is this the multiplication rule or addition rule?
My idea is that its

$\dbinom{60}{22} \dbinom{38}{22} \dbinom{16}{16} = 3.1479*10^{26}$ but this seems like too big of a number.

Comment: It depends on whether the two groups of 22 are distinguished or not. For example, if Persons 1-22 are in the first group, Persons 23-44 are in the second group, and the rest are in the third group, is that considered the same as having Persons 23-44 in the first group, Persons 1-22 in the second, and the rest in the third group?

Comment: No thats not the same, they would be considered different, its treatment assignments for a study.

Comment: @Shailesh, no this is the correct answer for distinguishable groups. The multinomial coefficient ${60 \choose 22,22,16} = \frac{60!}{22!22!16!}$ counts the number of ways to divide 60 individuals into distinguished groups of size 22, 22, and 16.

Comment: For *labelled* groups, your expression is correct. I have not checked the numerical evaluation. But huge numbers are common in this game, it is called the combinatorial explosion.

Answer (score 1):

Call one 22-size group A and the other B. Since, it matters which is which, then the number of ways to make the three groups are
$$\binom{60}{16}\binom{44}{22}\binom{22}{22} = \binom{60}{16,22,22} = 3.147908\times 10^{26},$$
which is the same as the original answer. In other words, I choose 16 to be in the small group. Then I am free to choose 22 from the remaining to be in A, and the I am left with group B.

Comment: would you be able to explain why its multiplication rather than addition? i keep confusing these two rules

Comment: Generally, when you run into an **OR** statement, that is when you add.

Comment: Sorry, the reason it is multiplication is because this is a bunch of AND statements to me. In other words, let $W$ be the number of ways I can make your groups, then the way I think of this is in terms of tasks. First task $T_1$ is to make a small group, then $T_2$ is to make group A, then $T_3$ is to make B. Then the number of ways to do this is
$$W = \#T_1\cdot \#T_2\cdot \#T_3.$$

Comment: So $\{T_1$ has to be 16 **AND** $T_2$ has to be 22 **AND** $T_3$ has to be 22$\}$.